# Obtaining JVM information from Tomcat Manager

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jvm

Working with Firebug with Firefox we see from Tomcat Manager/Server Status the following URL:

```
<a href="/manager/status?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=8EE95A7E3D6776DFEE4826EE3ED7ED9B">Server Status</a>
```

Or we see with our older servers:

```
<a href="/manager/status">Server Status</a>
```

And on the resulting page we see, for example:

## JVM

Free memory: 656.61 MB Total memory: 1979.75 MB Max memory: 1979.75 MB

Looking at the batch files from the bin folder from Tomcat, we see some interesting things that work fine from a command-line.

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -classpath "%CATALINA_HOME%\lib\catalina.jar" org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo
```

and this works great..

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/6.0.20
Server built:   May 14 2009 01:13:50
Server number:  6.0.20.0
OS Name:        Windows 2003 OS
Version:     5.2
Architecture:   x86
JVM Version:    1.6.0_17-b04 JVM
Vendor:     Sun Microsystems Inc.
```

What I would like to do is to take periodic samples from:

"http://localhost/manager/status" under the JVM and if below a certain level to warn us.

We do see the file:  /tomcat/webapps/manager/status.xsd

And we see:

```
<xs:complexType name="jvm">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="memory" type="memory"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="memory">
    <xs:attribute name="free" type="xs:long" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="total" type="xs:long" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="max" type="xs:long" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

What we really want to query is: "free".

However, we are bit stuck.

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -classpath "%CATALINA_HOME%\lib\catalina.jar" org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo.status
```

as an example.  This returns:

```
D:\>"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -classpath "%CATALINA_HOME%\lib\catalina.jar
" org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo.status
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/u
til/ServerInfo/status
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo
.status
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:303)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo.status.  Prog
ram will exit.
```

Understand, we could install YourKit or other similar tools, but we don't have the flexibility to install on these prod servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to scrape the status page, you should use JMX.

For testing (unsecured access), you can enable JMX by adding the following when starting Tomcat:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8000
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

If starting Tomcat from the command-line, these can be given by setting the `CATALINA_OPTS` environment variable.

Use `jconsole` to examine all the JMX values provide by Java and Tomcat. You be looking for this one:

```
java.lang
  Memory
    Attributes
      HeapMemoryUsage
```

You can also get these from Tomcat using the following URL if you setup a user with the `manager-jmx` role:

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/jmxproxy?get=java.lang:type=Memory&att=HeapMemoryUsage
```

In both cases, you'll find 4 values, e.g.:

```
committed   719323136
init        536870912
max        1908932608
used        409566448
```

Comment: And..  With this, "Free" should be: free=max-used
Please correct me if I am incorrect the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at :

http://localhost:8080/manager/text/serverinfo

if I understood your question

Comment: Not quite..  I do see the plain text version at http://localhost/manager/serverinfo but, what really want is: http://localhost/manager/status and the JVM memory: "Free memory" is what I am targeting.

Comment: VM info such as memory heap statistics can be obtained via `/manager/text/vminfo`. Just in case someone really wants to use the text interface and not JMX.